# How to query and return one entity with WindowsAzure.MobileServices

Tags: c#, node.js, azure

I have created a Mobile app in Azure with quick start, Xamarin forms and Node.js backend and downloaded the client application. There are some samples for `GetTodoItemsAsync` and `SaveTaskAsync` in  TodoItemManager.cs, but I need a function to query and select just one Todoitem by its name.

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<TodoItem>> GetTodoItemsAsync(bool syncItems = false)
{
    try
    {
#if OFFLINE_SYNC_ENABLED
        if (syncItems)
        {
            await this.SyncAsync();
        }
#endif
        IEnumerable<TodoItem> items = await todoTable
            .Where(todoItem => !todoItem.Done)
            .ToEnumerableAsync();

        return new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>(items);
    }
    catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code for the single getter function?

Comment: This is what i'm looking for. I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to return just one item by name should be (assuming the TodoItem has a Name property):

```
public async Task<TodoItem> GetTodoItemAsync(string name)
{
    try
    {
        TodoItem item = await todoTable
            .Where(todoItem => todoItem.Name.Equals(name))
            .Select(todoItem => todoItem)
            .ToListAsync()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return item;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"Exception: {0}", e.Message);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you gbellmann for your answer. I wrote this code before and i have this error with it: (Error CS1061 'IMobileServiceTableQuery<bool>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'IMobileServiceTableQuery<bool>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)). And another thing is that I need this code without async await and when I remove them I will get another error in return item.

Comment: Then adding `.ToListAsync()` before the `.FirstOrDefault()` should do the work. (It's trying to apply the FirstOrDefualt in the Service and not in the client.

Comment: Now i got "Task<List<bool>>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'". When I download C# backend from Azure it uses 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server;' and everything is OK and I'm able to run the query. But my backend is Node.js and uses 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;' and I get these errors.

Comment: Sorry, when I edited the answer to add the `.ToListAsync()` I also changed the `Where` clause to make it simpler for new devs, but forgot to add the `.Select()`. Already fixed the answer.

Comment: Now Task<List<TodoItem>>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'. There is no problem to write such a function in Backend but in client side in TodoItemManager.cs.

Comment: Finally I fixed it. I used the result of the function in another form and then used FirstOrDefault. Thank you for your help.